# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to implement Current UserName in SaveChangesAsync on ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Entity Framework and ASP.NET Identity Db Context.

I have these services.

Interface:

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public string UserName { get; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public string UserName { get; }

    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        UserName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
        UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    }
}
```

Then I called it in ApplicationDbContext as shown below.

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IDateTime dateTime)
        : base(options)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserRoleConfigurations());
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        foreach (var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (item.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Added:
                    item.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    item.Entity.DeletedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    item.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        OnBeforeSaveChanges(_currentUserService?.UserName);
        foreach (var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (item.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Added:
                    item.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    item.Entity.DeletedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    item.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
        )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task Save()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

In the application, when I implement it as:

```
 await _unitOfWork.Employees.InsertAsync(bankUser);
 await _unitOfWork.Save();
```

I expected it to also insert UserName in the CreatedBy field, but it is null.

But If I implement it directly as :

```
_currentUserService.UserName
```

inside the application, it works..

What could be wrong and how do I correct this?

Thanks

Comment: It will only work where `HttpContext` is present otherwise it will be null.

Comment: @Eldar - How do I achieve that? I need to add it from the ApplicationDbContext. Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you assign `UserName` and `UserId` right away when the service is constructed. At the time of the construction of your service there might not be a `HttpContext` to work with.

Try using the `HttpContextAccessor` in your getter like this:

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string UserName => this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;

    public string UserId => this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
}
```

By using the `HttpContextAccessor` when the property is accessed you make sure to get the currently valid one (if there is any).

Comment: It should not differ if the `HttpContextIdentityService` service is registered as `Scoped` and it should be.

Comment: @user1859022 - I got this error:  The type or namespace name 'IUserIdentityService' could not be found

Comment: @Ayobamilaye I modified my exmpale so you can paste it in...

Comment: @Eldar removed the binding part from the explanation to clarify that accessing the `HttpContext` in the constructur might be to early.

Comment: @user1859022 - I followed you code, but it's still null

Comment: @Ayobamilaye what is the context of this `UnitOfWork` ? Is this a part of the request pipeline at all?